# Chamar action com click de botão passando parâmetro

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Terei 3 botões, cada um com um id diferente, como faço para passar esse id para a ação do meu controller quando for clicado?

```
public IActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        var lista = _listaService.sites(id);
        return View(lista);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar os Helpers do Razor para criar links para ações passando o id específico de cada botão. Na sua view você pode fazer:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", new { id = 1 })" class="btn btn-primary">ID = 1</a>
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", new { id = 2 })" class="btn btn-primary">ID = 2</a>
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", new { id = 3 })" class="btn btn-primary">ID = 3</a>
```

ou:

```
@Html.ActionLink("ID = 1", "Index", new { id = 1 }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
@Html.ActionLink("ID = 2", "Index", new { id = 2 }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
@Html.ActionLink("ID = 3", "Index", new { id = 3 }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
```

Note que estou usando âncoras no HTML passando a classe do Bootstrap `btn btn-primary` para que o link seja renderizado como botão ao invés de link. Dessa forma você não vai precisar de criar três forms com um botão cada ou usar jQuery vinculando no evento onclick do botão.

EDIT: Se precisa que o id não apareça na url, use `Html.BeginForm` para cada botão atribuindo o `name` e o `value` conforme exemplo abaixo:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="1" name="id">ID = 1</button>
    }        
<br />
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="2" name="id">ID = 2</button>
}
<br />
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="3" name="id">ID = 3</button>
}
<br />
@if (Model != 0)
{
    <p>Olá o ID agora é @Model.ToString()</p>
}
```

Na Controller faça assim:

```
public class TesteController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        int id = 0;
        if (Request.Form["id"] != null)
            id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["id"]);

        //faça o que precisar fazer com a id

        return View(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Procuro uma forma sem usar rota, de maneira que eu apenas chame a action e passe o id, mas sem aparecer nada na url

Comment: crie um form para cada botão com método Post, assim o id não vai aparecer na url, se não estou enganado uma outra forma de fazer isso seria colocar a anotação [HttpPost] na Action Index no seu Controller

Comment: O que eu uso para especificar o id no form?

Comment: Acredito que já tenha conseguido resolver rs, mas editei minha resposta de acordo com seu comentário. Ah e esquece o que eu falei sobre usar o [HttpPost], eu estava mesmo enganado.

Comment: Eu vou ver aqui depois mas acho que dá pra fazer com um form só, basta adicionar o evento `onclick=` e atribuir à `"submit();"` na tag button, assim os três botões ficam em um form só.